# Find and replace color on button click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, colors

I have a SVG with multiple `linearGradient` elements and I want to change the value `#4D4D4D` with `#ff0000` in the entire SVG when a button is pressed.

Is there a way to search the value in the entire SVG and replace it with the color I want?

```
<svg>
  <g id="Group_Volute_Chamber">

    <linearGradient id="SVGID_2_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="6.8694" y1="93.75" x2="30.2922" y2="93.75" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 112.5)">
      <stop offset="0.01" stop-color="#4D4D4D" />
      <!--4d4d4d  style="stop-color:#4F4D4D"-->
      <stop offset="0.51" style="stop-color:#F5F5F5" />
      <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#4D4D4D" />
    </linearGradient>
    <path fill="url(#SVGID_2_)" stroke="#4C4C4C" stroke-width="0.25" d="M6.869,3.266V37.5h23.423v-0.45V3.266l-1.577-2.703L27.59,0   h-0.676h-1.239H10.248L7.545,1.577L6.982,2.703L6.869,3.266" />

    <linearGradient id="SVGID_3_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="6.8694" y1="78.1523" x2="30.2922" y2="78.1523" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 112.5)">
      <stop offset="0.01" style="stop-color:#4D4D4D" />
      <stop offset="0.51" style="stop-color:#F5F5F5" />
      <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#4D4D4D" />
    </linearGradient>
    <path fill="url(#SVGID_3_)" stroke="#4C4C4C" stroke-width="0.25" d="M6.869,34.347h23.423" />

    <linearGradient id="SVGID_4_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="6.8694" y1="105.8555" x2="30.2922" y2="105.8555" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 112.5)">
      <stop offset="0.01" style="stop-color:#4D4D4D" />
      <stop offset="0.51" style="stop-color:#F5F5F5" />
      <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#4D4D4D" />
    </linearGradient>
    <path fill="url(#SVGID_4_)" stroke="#4C4C4C" stroke-width="0.25" d="M6.869,6.645h23.423" />
  </g>
</svg>

<button type="button" onclick="test()">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Well, nothing so far because I don't know how could I approach what  I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use each() and css() functions, also, please notice that color values in jQuery are returned in RGB format, which is rgb(77, 77, 77) for #4D4D4D, so you can use this function:

```
jQuery('svg stop').each( function() {
        var color = jQuery(this).css('stop-color');
      if ( color === 'rgb(77, 77, 77)') {
        jQuery(this).css('stop-color', '#ff0000');
      }
  });
```

You can try it in the test link, I have updated it for you: https://jsfiddle.net/HebaF/7jvzb34L/8/

Comment: It works. Thanks!
With jQuery('svg stop').each( function() you're searching for all <stop> tags in the whole SVG, right?

Comment: You are welcome anytime! Yes, that's right :) also, the code gets and replaces the value of stop-color only.

Comment: One more question. If I'd have had two groups in that SVG and wanted to change stop color just for one group, how could I difference them?

Comment: you can add id or class attribute to svg element to differentiate the svg elements.

Comment: So I could apply the code provided by you depending on group's id?

Comment: Yes, just add the svg id like this: 'svg#id stop' where the svg is like: <svg id="id"></svg> :)

Comment: If I do like this, the color would not be applied to both groups? I suppose the if would give an id to each group, my problem should be solved.
<svg>
<g id="Group_Volute_Chamber">
<linearGradient id="SVGID_2_" ...>....</linearGradient >
</g>
<g id="anotherGroup">
<linearGradient id="SVGID_3_" ...>....</linearGradient >
</g>
And depinding the group I want to apply your code.

Comment: oh, you meant inside the same id? also it does work with groups inside svg, just use id attribute :) and in this case the selector will be jQuery('svg #id stop')

Comment: The svg has two groups. One group with id="Group_Volute_Chamber" and other with id="anotherGroup". So if want to apply just for the group with id="anotherGroup", it should be something like: jQuery('svg #anotherGroup stop')?

Comment: That's right :) Please check this guide on writing SVG http://svgpocketguide.com/book/